# Is it possible to use util class to set a property in XML bean using SpEL?

Tags: spring

Here is my bean definition:

```
<bean id="myBean" scope="step" class="com.test.spring.batch.MyBean">    
    <property name="resources" value="#{ResourceUtils.getResources(jobExecutionContext['key'])}"/>
</bean>
```

I need to pass a Spring bean (from Spring Batch context) to the static method of util class `ResourceUtils.getResources(String)` and set resource file to MyBean property.

Now Spring says `Cannot resolve variable ResourceUtils`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Spring [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-types), when you're using type in SpEL expression you have to use it next way:

```
<bean id="myBean" scope="step" class="com.test.spring.batch.MyBean">    
    <property name="resources" value="#{T(com.mypackage.ResourceUtils).getResources(jobExecutionContext['key'])}"/>
</bean>
```

In other words, you have to use `T()` construction and fully qualified class name (`com.mypackage` in this example).